# Stripe payments not going through with React JS

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I was working with Stripe on a localhost and everything was working perfectly but when I try to switch all the keys to live and run it on Netlify, it seems the payments do not go through. It only shows up as a log in the stripe dashboard.

It seems to be the below block of code I'm having issues with.

```
fetch('/stripe-charge', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(bodyObject)
        })
```

If I change the stripe address above to http://localhost:9000/stripe-charge, everything works perfectly. Am I just not targeting the folder properly?

Folder structure:

```
main site folder
    - src
        - components
        - layouts
        - pages
        - images
    - functions
        - stripe-charge.js
```

Comment: /stripe-charge is end point of your backed service. It’s not the folder name which you have. Your backend service is running on local host 9000 port and your Api path is /stripe-charge so while doing fetch you need to specify absolute path like localhost:9000/stripe-charge for fetch to work fine. What you understand till now is not correct I guess

Answer (score 0):

As @Think-Twice mentioned, `/stripe-charge` should be served a server side API endpoint instead of a file names.

What you can do in to serve `stripe-charge.js` in `express.js` [0]

```
 const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const port = 3000
  app.post('/stripe-charge', (req, res) => {
    // Move y=your stripe-charge.js logic 
  })
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(Example app listening on port ${port}!))
```

And then follow `Netlify` docs to do the deployment[1]

[0] http://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

[1] https://www.netlify.com/docs/